# GCC C vector extension: How to cast arbitrary aligned array/pointer to vector type?

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

I am new to GCC C's vector extensions. I read in the manual that vectors can be cast to and from any type through use of a cast. However, I am unclear how this is performed, as the obvious method fails:

```
typedef int8_t s8a __attribute__((aligned (16)));
typedef int8_t v16s8 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
s8a *x = _mm_malloc(512,16); // Grab some aligned mem for my int8s
x[0] = 4; x[2] = 1; x[5] = 7; x[15] = 1; // the rest should be junk
v16s8 y = (v16s8)x; // assign the aligned memory to a vector type
```

I get:

```
vec.c:22:2: error: can't convert value to a vector
  v16s8 y = (v16s8)x;
```

How can I cast arbitrary memory locations (with known alignment equal to or better than the vector) to the vector types?

Thanks!

Comment: Your data pointed to by x is not aligned, use _mm_malloc(size,alignment)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be like any reinterpreting cast: `v16s8 y = *(v16s8*)(&x);`?

Comment: `v16s8 y = *(v16s8*)(&x);` compiles but immediately crashes when run.

Comment: Try `v16s8 y = *(v16s8*)x;`